# Effective way of find Total number of even divisors of the number

Tags: java

I have to find number of even number of divisor of given number. For this i tried.I am getting correct output but i am getting time complexity more than required.
Question :- First line contains the number of testcases T, followed by T lines each containing an integer N 
output should be - **For each testcase, print the required answer in a single line**.
**How can i reduce complexity for this given code.Or can anyone please suggest more efficient way**...

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        // Read input from stdin and provide input before running
        String frt = "";
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String line = br.readLine();    
        int T = Integer.parseInt(line);     
        int[] inp = new int[T];
        for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {           
            int x = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            inp[i] = x;

        }
        int[] ans = new int[T];
        int count = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
            int x = inp[i];
            if (x % 2 == 0) {
                for (int j = 2; j <= x / 2; j = j + 2) {
                    if (x % j == 0)
                        count++;
                }
            } else
                count = 0;
            ans[i] = count;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < T; i++)
            System.out.println(ans[i]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 import java.io.*;

 class Ideone
 {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
    {

      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      int T = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
      int i,j,k,n;

      int[] inp = new int[T];
      for (i = 0; i < T; i++) {
      inp[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
      }

     //Find all the primes numbers till the square-root of 10^9.
     int MAX, root, arrLen;
     MAX=1000000000;
     arrLen=(int)Math.sqrt(MAX);  // arrLen=31622 
     boolean[] primes=new boolean[arrLen+2]; // No need to find all the primes numbers till MAX

     primes[0]=primes[1]=false;
     for(i=2;i<arrLen;i++)
           primes[i]=true;


     // Using Sieve of Eratosthenes
    // Square root of 31622 is 177.8
    root=(int)Math.sqrt(arrLen); // root=177
    for(i=2;i<=root;i++)
    {
       if(primes[i])
       {
           n=i*i;
           k=0;

           //arrLen is the length of primes array.
           for(j=n; j<arrLen; k+=1, j=n+(i*k))
                  primes[j]=false;
       }
   }

    int[] ans = new int[T];
    for( i = 0; i < T; i++) {
         n = inp[i];

         if(n%2==1)
         {
             ans[i]=0; // Odd numbers will have 0 even divisors
         }
         else
         {

          int[] facts=new int[50];
          for(k=0;k<50;k++)
              facts[k]=1;

        facts[0]=0; // fact[0] will contain the highest power of 2 that divides n.
        while(n%2==0)
        {
             facts[0]+=1;
             n=n/2;
        }           

        // Prime factorizing n
        j=1;
        for( k=3; k<arrLen; k+=2)
        {
            if(primes[k] && n%k==0)
            {
                while(n%k==0)
               {
                    facts[j]+=1;
                    n=n/k;
               }
               j+=1;
            }
            if(n==1)  // To check if n has been completely divided or not.
               break;
       }

       if(n!=1) // To check if there is any prime factor greater than the square root of MAX.
       {
            facts[j]+=1;
            j+=1;
       }

       int count=1;
       for(k=0;k<j;k++)
            count=count*facts[k];

        ans[i]=count;
       }
}

   for ( i = 0; i < T; i++)
           System.out.println(ans[i]);

     }
 }
```

I am of the feeling that this question might have been posted on any competitive coding platform, probably like HackerEarth. If so, then please don't post direct questions on StackOverFlow(in my opinion).
Anyways, I have tested my code and it runs correctly.
In questions where you are not able to reduce time complexity, first make sure that unnecessary objects are not created. Object creation in the memory is a time consuming operation. Avoid irrelevant creation of object and variables. The code above can still be optimized, but that will reduce it's readability. :)

Also before approaching a problem, try to figure out various test cases. Like odd numbers will have 0 even divisors. So by checking whether a number is odd, can reduce several operations.

A bit more explanation to the above code:
Number Of Divisor of A Number are: (N1+1)(N2+1)(N3+1).... Where N1,N2,N3 etc are Powers Of Prime Multiples of the number.
Now if N1 is for 2(the only even prime number),
then Number of Even Divisors of the Number are: N1*(N2+1)*(N3+1)...

In the facts[] array, facts[0] corresponds to N1, while N2, N3 etc are stored in facts[1],facts[2], etc.
facts[0] is initialized with 0, while others are initialized with 1.
The count stores the final product: N1*(N2+1)*(N3+1)... which is equal to the number of Even divisors of the original number.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple trick for this,first compute the prime factorization of `720`,which is `2^4×3^2×5`,the total number of factors here is `3x2×5=30`, and number of odd factors (number of factors of the odd primes)=`3×2=6`,subtracting gives number of even factors = `24`.This method works for any number.

NOTE: If the number has no odd factors i.e,the prime factorization is of the form `2a`,then the number of number of even factors is a and number of odd factors is 1.

Comment: Even I tried this.but what if number is divided by 7 too . like 56. Then 1st I have to find prime factor then power of all the prime factor. Will it not increase complexity more????? Uma kanth can you please post generalized code.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, shorter and simpler:

```
public class Solution {

    public static int numberOfEvenDivisors(int n) {
        if (n % 2 == 1)
            return 0;
        int evenDivisors = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < Math.sqrt(n) + 1; i++) {
            if ((i % 2 == 0) && (n % i == 0))
                evenDivisors++;
            if ((n % (n / i) == 0) && (n / i) % 2 == 0)
                evenDivisors++;
            if ((i * i == n) && (i % 2 == 0))
                evenDivisors--;
        }
        return evenDivisors;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //test here 
    }
}
```

Here is short explanation:
When `n` is odd we return 0, there are no even divisors.
In the first `if` we check whether `i` is a divisor and whether `i` is even. When yes, wo do increment the divisors counter. Note that we start with 1. This is necessary because here we know that `n` is even and `n` is its own divisor.

In second `if` we increment divisors counter if `n / i` is even and `i` is a divisor. If `i` is even, we counted it already in first `if`. And we know that `(n/i) >= i`, because we count `i` only up to square root of `n`.

And in the last, third `if` we check the case whether `i` is a even divisor that is square root of `n` (for example `i == 4`, `n == 16`). Here we decrement number of divisors because we do not want to count same divisor twice. That is.
P.S. We assume `n >= 1`.

Answer (score -2):

This for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
        int x = inp[i];
        if (x % 2 == 0) {
            for (int j = 2; j <= x / 2; j = j + 2) {
                if (x % j == 0)
                    count++;
        } else
            count = 0;
        ans[i] = count;
    }
```

could be changed to

```
for (int i = 0; i < T; i+=2) {
        int x = inp[i];
        for (int j = 2; j <= x / 2; j = j + 2) {
            if (x % j == 0)
                count++;
        if(count != 1)
            count = 0;
        ans[i] = count;
    }
```

so that it will make the for loop run half as many times.

Comment: There is a problem with your code. I guess it won't compile. That `else` doesn't have a corresponding `if`.

Comment: why `i+=2`? why are you skipping the second test case?